# Matlab - GUI - Modify a variable by changing it in an other callback

Tags: matlab, loops, user-interface, variables, global

I want to make a simple program that displays an increasing number in a loop  upon pressing a run button and change that value by pressing an other button while in the loop. The program I came up with using what I've found so far increases the number and displays it correctly, but the variables I use are apparently independant from each other so whenever I reset the value to 0, the loop continues where it was left before the reset.

```
% --- Executes on button press in stop.
function stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
test = 0;
set(handles.display, 'String', num2str(test));
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in run.
function run_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
test = 1;
while test > 0
    test = test + 1;
    set(handles.display, 'String', num2str(test));
    guidata(hObject, handles);
    pause(1);
end
```

Any idea how to make this test variable global, how to initialize it and where I should put it in the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior! The scope of the variable `test` is local to each function, so you cannot change it in one function and expect the changed value to appear in the other function.

There are a few options around this! For example, you can use the `handles` structure to pass around "global" variables. In your code, you would have to modify it like so:

```
% --- Executes on button press in stop.
function stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles.test = 0;
set(handles.display, 'String', num2str(handles.test));
guidata(hObject, handles); % Store the changed handles structure

% --- Executes on button press in start.
function run_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles.test = 1;
while handles.test > 0
    handles.test = handles.test + 1;
    set(handles.display, 'String', num2str(handles.test));
    guidata(hObject, handles); % stores the changed handles structure
    pause(1);
    handles = guidata(hObject); % updates "handles" to see the change!
end
```

This is a pretty standard approach, but it has a few drawbacks: It's super easy to accidentally omit updating or retrieving the `handles` structure. Furthermore, since the two functions run in parallel, they are susceptible to race conditions.

A second method is to use the `global` statement. It's inserted easily:

```
% --- Executes on button press in stop.
function stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global test;
test = 0;
set(handles.display, 'String', num2str(test));
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in run.
function run_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global test;
test = 1;
while test > 0
    test = test + 1;
    set(handles.display, 'String', num2str(test));
    guidata(hObject, handles);
    pause(1);
end
```

But this too comes with a few drawback: Now the variable `test` is truly global. It can be changed in other scripts, functions, or GUIs as well, so you should choose a more unique name than `test`, and be careful in general. Also, when the (singleton) GUI is restarted without closing it first, the GUI's visual state, the contents of the `handles` structure, and the contents of the global variables can become "out of sync". I got bitten by this twice, so I don't use this method anymore.

A third method embraces the fact that the variable `test` should always be linked to the GUI text field. It therefore uses the string in the `display` field in place of a variable. Essentially that means using `get`, `set`, `str2double`, and `num2str` a lot:

```
% --- Executes on button press in stop.
function stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.display, 'String', num2str(0));
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in start.
function run_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.display, 'String', num2str(1));
while str2double(get(handles.display, 'String')) > 0
    set(handles.display, 'String', ...
        num2str(str2double(get(handles.display, 'String')) + 1));
    guidata(hObject, handles);
    pause(1);
end
```

It's verbose, but it's what I use in these cases. It is the most robust solution, especially when restarting a (singleton) GUI without closing it first.

Comment: The first method works as intended ! I actually used it earlier in my tests but I wasn't aware of that line "handles = guidata(hObject); % updates "handles" to see the change!" so it was missing and so it behaved like the code in my request.
Thanks !

Comment: Regarding the first and third method, what would be the most efficient ? I'm trying to make a real-time processing program for audio and I need to be careful about that

Comment: My gut tells me neither method is terribly efficient - the method with the `global` statement is probably fastest. Between the first and the third method, I guess the first method is faster. But only a test can decide for sure. Real-time audio can be tricky, and you might have to resolve to more advanced magic. In any case, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare your variable as global. This will do.

```
% --- Executes on button press in stop.
function stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global test;
test = 0;
set(handles.display, 'String', num2str(test));
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in run.
function run_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global test;
test = 1;
while test > 0
    test = test + 1;
    set(handles.display, 'String', num2str(test));
    guidata(hObject, handles);
    pause(1);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if your project is small and fits into a single M-file, you can solve this most easily by using [nested functions](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html).

If you are making your GUI using guide, then you can do this most easily in the following way: (make sure you save a copy first of the auto-generated m-file from GUI editing)

1. open the m-file
2. If the functions are not ended with keyword `end`, then add it to all functions defined, except the very first function (whose name is on the m-file)
3. put an extra `end` at the very bottom of your m-file

After this, any variables that you define in the top function will be available to the lower functions (the nested ones, who are also the callbacks). The standard Matlab editor will after this color highlight your variables differently if they have scope across many functions